# How to specialize templated operator overload of template class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a matrix class like this:

```
template <class Type, size_t x_dim, size_t y_dim>
class mat {
  private:
    std::array<Type, x_dim * y_dim> m_data;
    size_t xdim = x_dim, ydim = y_dim; // xdim=no of cols   ydim= no of rows
public:
    // normal constructor to make unit matrix
     mat() {
        for (int i = 0; i < y_dim; i++)
            for (size_t j = 0; j < x_dim; j++)
                operator()(i, j) = i == j ? 1 : 0;
    }
    
    //constructor to take in array
    mat(const std::array<Type, x_dim * y_dim> &in) {
        assert(in.size() == x_dim * y_dim);
        m_data = in;
    }
    
    // () overload to access elements of matrix
    Type &operator()(const size_t &r, const size_t &c){
        assert(r >= 0 && r < y_dim && c >= 0 && c < x_dim);
        return m_data[r * xdim + c];
    }

    // * overload to multiply two matrices 
    template <size_t lx, size_t ly>
    mat<Type, x_dim, ly> operator*(const mat<Type, lx, ly> &in) const {
        assert(x_dim == ly);
        mat<Type, x_dim, ly> ret;
        int i, j, k;
        for (i = 0; i < y_dim; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < lx; j++) {
                ret(i, j) = 0;
                for (k = 0; k < x_dim; k++)
                    ret(i, j) += operator()(i, k) * in(k, j);
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    template <>
    mat<Type, xdim, 4> operator*<4,4>(const mat<Type, 4, 4> &in) const;
#endif
};
```

How do I specialize the `operator*` function for any `mat<Type,4,4>` to remove for loops. I tried code below written outside the class defined above:

```
template <class Type, size_t x_dim, size_t y_dim>
template <size_t lx, size_t ly>
mat<Type, 4, 4> mat<Type, 4, 4>::operator*<4, 4>(const mat<Type, 4, 4> &in) const {
    return mat<Type, 4, 4>({
        operator()(0, 0) * in(0, 0) + operator()(0, 1) * in(1, 0) + operator()(0, 2) * in(2, 0) + operator()(0, 3) * in(3, 0),
        operator()(0, 0) * in(0, 1) + operator()(0, 1) * in(1, 1) + operator()(0, 2) * in(2, 1) + operator()(0, 3) * in(3, 1),
        operator()(0, 0) * in(0, 2) + operator()(0, 1) * in(1, 2) + operator()(0, 2) * in(2, 2) + operator()(0, 3) * in(3, 2),
        operator()(0, 0) * in(0, 3) + operator()(0, 1) * in(1, 3) + operator()(0, 2) * in(2, 3) + operator()(0, 3) * in(3, 3),
        operator()(1, 0) * in(0, 0) + operator()(1, 1) * in(1, 0) + operator()(1, 2) * in(2, 0) + operator()(1, 3) * in(3, 0),
        operator()(1, 0) * in(0, 1) + operator()(1, 1) * in(1, 1) + operator()(1, 2) * in(2, 1) + operator()(1, 3) * in(3, 1),
        operator()(1, 0) * in(0, 2) + operator()(1, 1) * in(1, 2) + operator()(1, 2) * in(2, 2) + operator()(1, 3) * in(3, 2),
        operator()(1, 0) * in(0, 3) + operator()(1, 1) * in(1, 3) + operator()(1, 2) * in(2, 3) + operator()(1, 3) * in(3, 3),
        operator()(2, 0) * in(0, 0) + operator()(2, 1) * in(1, 0) + operator()(2, 2) * in(2, 0) + operator()(2, 3) * in(3, 0),
        operator()(2, 0) * in(0, 1) + operator()(2, 1) * in(1, 1) + operator()(2, 2) * in(2, 1) + operator()(2, 3) * in(3, 1),
        operator()(2, 0) * in(0, 2) + operator()(2, 1) * in(1, 2) + operator()(2, 2) * in(2, 2) + operator()(2, 3) * in(3, 2),
        operator()(2, 0) * in(0, 3) + operator()(2, 1) * in(1, 3) + operator()(2, 2) * in(2, 3) + operator()(2, 3) * in(3, 3),
        operator()(3, 0) * in(0, 0) + operator()(3, 1) * in(1, 0) + operator()(3, 2) * in(2, 0) + operator()(3, 3) * in(3, 0),
        operator()(3, 0) * in(0, 1) + operator()(3, 1) * in(1, 1) + operator()(3, 2) * in(2, 1) + operator()(3, 3) * in(3, 1),
        operator()(3, 0) * in(0, 2) + operator()(3, 1) * in(1, 2) + operator()(3, 2) * in(2, 2) + operator()(3, 3) * in(3, 2),
        operator()(3, 0) * in(0, 3) + operator()(3, 1) * in(1, 3) + operator()(3, 2) * in(2, 3) + operator()(3, 3) * in(3, 3)};    
   }); 
}
```

I get this error from intellisense of msvc:
[image]

and this error from the compiler:
`1>Project\Application\include\maths.h(723,34): warning C4346: 'mat<Type,4,4>::*': dependent name is not a type`

How do I solve this?

Comment: there are several problems in the code not related to your question. Eg `operator()(i, j) = i == j ? 1 : 0;` but `operator()` returns a `const`

Comment: you cannot specialize a single method without specializing the whole class template. You can make `operator*`  a free function

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number could you please give an example?

Comment: What's the point of the `xdim` and `ydim` variables? Especially since you barely even use them instead of `x_dim` and `y_dim`.

Comment: my bad Im kinda new to cpp. thanks for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 3):

I will use a simpler example:

```
template <typename T,size_t x>
struct foo {    
    template <size_t y>
    foo<T,x+y> operator*(const foo<T,y>& other){ return {};}
};
```

You cannot specialize `foo::operator*` for `x==4` without specializing `foo`. Though, you can supply a non-member `operator*` and overload it:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T,size_t x> struct foo {};

template <typename T,size_t x,size_t y>
foo<T,x+y> operator*(const foo<T,x>& a,const foo<T,y>& b){ 
    std::cout << "general operator*\n";
    return {};
}

template <typename T>
foo<T,4> operator*(const foo<T,4>& a,const foo<T,4>& b){
    std::cout << "4*4\n";
    return {};
}

int main() {
    foo<int,4> f;
    foo<int,3> g;
    f*f;
    g*g;
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/KrvTYn89K):

```
4*4
general operator*
```

Answer (score 0):

[**temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-16**](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.spec#temp.expl.spec-16)

> A member or a member template may be nested within many enclosing class templates. In an explicit specialization for such a member, the member declaration shall be preceded by a `template<>` for each enclosing class template that is explicitly specialized.